# Calculating the Volume of a Cylindrical Shell

Tags: calculus, volume

[image]

Hey I'm trying to solve this problem and I'm stuck. The integral I'm using to solve this problem is the integral from $0$ to $4$ of $2{\pi}y(27 - (y + 2)^3)$ but the answer isn't correct. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find $\int_0^{1} 2\pi r(y)h(y)\;dy=\int_0^{1}2\pi y(32-((y+2)^3+5))\;dy$